# x64 Assembly zeroing an array (8 bytes at a time)

Tags: array, assembly

Is there a better way of implementing this other than using simd instructions?

What is the best way of dealing with arrays not divisible by 8, as in the code where if there are less than 8 bytes left to zero they just get zeroed 1 by 1?

Maybe it is faster to check how many bytes there are left and then zero them 2 bytes or 4 bytes at a time?

Does the checking outweigh the cost of doing them 1 by 1?

This is just a test for me to try to learn assembly so any, even small, improvements and tips are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
.code
ZeroArray proc
    cmp edx, 0   
    jle Finished ; Check if count is 0

    cmp edx, 8     
    jl SetupLessThan8Bytes ; Check if counter is less than 8

    mov r8d, edx ; Storing the original count
    shr edx, 3   ; Bit shifts the counter to the right by 3 (equal to dividing by 8), works because 2^3 is equal to 8
    mov r9d, edx ; Stores the divided count to be able to check how many single byte zeros the program has to do

MainLoop:
    mov qword ptr [rcx], 0 ; Set the next 8 bytes (qword) to 0
    add rcx, 8             ; Move pointer along the array by 8 bytes
    dec edx                ; Decrement the counter
    jnz MainLoop           ; If counter is not equal to 0 jump to MainLoop

    shl r9d, 3   ; Bit shifts the stored divided counter to the left by 3 (equal to multiplying by 8), 2^3 again
    sub r8d, r9d ; Subs the counts from eachother, if it equals zero all bytes are zeroed, otherwise r8d equals the amount of bytes left
    je Finished

SetFinalBytesLoop:
    mov byte ptr [rcx], 0 ; Sets the last byte of the array to 0
    inc rcx
    dec r8d
    jnz SetFinalBytesLoop

Finished:
    ret

SetupLessThan8Bytes:
    mov r8d, edx ; Mov the value of edx into r8d so the same code can be used in SetFinalBytesLoop
    jmp SetFinalBytesLoop

ZeroArray endp
end
```

Comment: You are using MASM and Visual Studio is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I am and I'm calling the function from c++. @Will

Comment: Is the second parameter of ZeroArray the number of qwords or number of bytes?

Comment: There are lots of different ways of going about this.  Which one is fastest tends to change from CPU to CPU.  For example, looking at the source for the MSVC `memset` function (which is basically what you are doing), you can see it testing whether the current CPU supports "Enhanced Fast Strings" as it selects which approach to use. As you say this is for educational purposes, how about looking at the `stosb/stosw/stosd/stosq` instructions? Combined with the `rep` prefix they can produce small, easy-to-understand code that is a common alternative if you don't want to use SIMD instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Shave off a byte

> ```
>     cmp  edx, 0   
>     jle  Finished            ; Check if count is 0
> ```

Using `cmp` is certainly not wrong, but the optimal way to check for any inappropriate counter value would be to use the `test` instruction.

```
    test edx, edx
    jle  Finished            ; Check if count is 0
```

Bypassing when the counter is zero is fine, but perhaps a negative counter value should rather be considered an error and handled accordingly?

### Don't loose yourself in jumping around

> ```
>     cmp  edx, 8     
>     jl   SetupLessThan8Bytes ; Check if counter is less than 8
>     mov  r8d, edx            ; Storing the original count
>     ...
>     ...
> SetupLessThan8Bytes:
>     mov  r8d, edx
>     jmp  SetFinalBytesLoop
> ```

When the counter in `EDX` is smaller than 8, you jump to *SetupLessThan8Bytes* where you just make a convenient copy of the counter and then jump again to *SetFinalBytesLoop*.
If you move the instruction that makes a copy of the original counter to right before where you compare the counter to 8, you can save yourself from writing 3 lines of code (a label, a `mov`, and a `jmp`). Moreover the program becomes clearer.

```
    mov  r8d, edx            ; Storing the original count
    cmp  edx, 8     
    jl   SetFinalBytesLoop   ; Check if counter is less than 8
```

### You don't even have to compare to 8 at all!

When you shift the counter in `EDX` 3 times to the right in order to find out how many qwords you have to process, you can look at the zero flag. If the ZF is set (meaning no qwords at all), you instantely *know* that the counter is in the range [1,7], and so the above snippet becomes:

```
    mov  r8d, edx            ; Storing the original count
    shr  edx, 3              ; Equal to dividing by 8
    jz   SetFinalBytesLoop   ; Jump if counter is less than 8
```

### Easier calculation of leftovers

> ```
>     mov  r9d, edx
>     ...
>     shl  r9d, 3
>     sub  r8d, r9d
>     je   Finished
> SetFinalBytesLoop:
> ```

The way you find out about the number of left over bytes is too complicated. It's correct but needlessly involved. Basically all it takes is *anding* the original counter with 7 to extract the lowest 3 bits. Simpler, shorter, and using one register less which in future programs will always be handy:

```
    and  r8d, 7
    jz   Finished
SetFinalBytesLoop:
```

### Smaller instructions are generally better

With the 32-bit immediate value, the `mov` instruction in the *MainLoop* is quite long (7 bytes). You can store the zero in `RAX` and move that to memory. This also eliminates the need for the mention "qword ptr ":

```
    xor  rax, rax            ; Equivalent to MOV EAX, 0
MainLoop:
    mov  [rcx], rax          ; Set the next 8 bytes (qword) to 0
    add  rcx, 8              ; Move pointer along the array by 8 bytes
    dec  edx                 ; Decrement the counter
    jnz  MainLoop            ; If counter is not equal to 0 jump to MainLoop
```

---

### Your program with all the above applied

```
    xor  rax, rax
    test edx, edx
    jle  Finished            ; Check if count is LE 0
    mov  r8d, edx            ; Copy of the original count
    shr  edx, 3              ; Gives number of qwords
    jz   SetFinalBytesLoop   ; Jump if counter is less than 8
MainLoop:
    mov  [rcx], rax          ; RAX=0 Set the next 8 bytes (qword) to 0
    add  rcx, 8              ; Step per 8 bytes
    dec  edx                 ; Dec the counter
    jnz  MainLoop
    and  r8d, 7              ; Remainder from division by 8
    jz   Finished
SetFinalBytesLoop:
    mov  [rcx], al           ; AL=0 Sets the last bytes of the array to 0
    inc  rcx                 ; Step per 1 byte
    dec  r8d                 ; Dec counter
    jnz  SetFinalBytesLoop
Finished:
    ret
```

I've moved the `xor rax, rax` higher up in the code so *SetFinalBytesLoop* can benefit from using the register `AL` vs the immediate 0.

---

### The optimization

The most important optimization that you can apply to your program is making sure that the qword value that you write is aligned on a qword boundary, so a memory address that is divisible by 8.
The extra alignment loop will at most iterate 7 times.

```
    xor  rax, rax
    test edx, edx
    jle  Finished            ; Check if count is LE 0

    jmp  TestAligned
AlignLoop:
    mov  [rcx], al
    inc  rcx
    dec  edx
    jz   Finished
TestAligned:
    test rcx, 7              ; Is this a qword aligned address?
    jnz  AlignLoop           ; Not yet!

    mov  r8d, edx            ; Copy of the (reduced) original count
    shr  edx, 3              ; Gives number of qwords
    jz   SetFinalBytesLoop   ; Jump if counter is less than 8
MainLoop:
    mov  [rcx], rax          ; RAX=0 Set the next 8 bytes (qword) to 0
    add  rcx, 8              ; Step per 8 bytes
    dec  edx                 ; Dec the counter
    jnz  MainLoop
    and  r8d, 7              ; Remainder from division by 8
    jz   Finished
SetFinalBytesLoop:
    mov  [rcx], al           ; AL=0 Sets the last bytes of the array to 0
    inc  rcx                 ; Step per 1 byte
    dec  r8d                 ; Dec counter
    jnz  SetFinalBytesLoop
Finished:
    ret
```